# In which version was === introduced in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, equality

I'm asking this question as I feel it's more appropriate to separate it from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738627/why-can-have-some-odd-behavior-in-javascript).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting talk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: Another SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803518/languages-that-always-had-triple-equals

Comment: @mplungjan: I brought up the SO discussion you talked about though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `===` operator was introduced in Javascript 1.3 and ECMA 2.6.2 Edition 3.

Reference

- [Mozilla Developer Network: Comparison Operators](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Specification which adds the member (thanks Dave!)

- [ECMA-262 3rd Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

Comment: For fun, a link to the actual spec where it was added: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: That first MDN link seems to be dead. [This archived page](https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/JavaScript/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1-3.html) lists the changes in JS 1.3, which was released in Netscape Navigator 4.5 before the 3rd edition of ECMA-262 was finalized.

Answer (score 2):

the strict equality operator was introduced in version 1.3